# Why isn't my post data displaying in my homepage

Tags: sanity, next.js13

I'm using NextJS 13 and Sanity.io to build a digital newspaper. I coded a schema and a client, I'm also fetching the data with groq:

```
import { Post } from "@/types/Post";
import { createClient, groq } from "next-sanity"

export async function getPosts(): Promise<Post[]> {
    const client = createClient({
        projectId: 'p7dk6747',
        dataset: 'production',
        apiVersion: "2023-03-04",
        useCdn: true
    });
    
    return client.fetch(
        groq`*[_type == "post"]{
            _id,
            _createdAt,
            title,
            slug,
            thumbnail,
            content
        }`
    )
}
```

I then try to map through my data to display it on the homepage, but the `posts` variable returns an empty array.

```
import { getPosts } from "@/sanity/sanity-utils";

export default async function Home() {
  const posts = await getPosts()
  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <div key={post._id}>{post.title}</div>
      ))}
      I'm the home page
    </div>
  );
}
```

I know this is not the conventional way to map through my data once fetched, but it should work just fine in NextJS 13 and it doesn't log any errors, not even on the browser.

I was expecting the `post.title` to display my posts title on the homepage.